# Saving to Parse database from Google Apps Script

Tags: parsing, google-apps-script, parse-platform

I'm trying to save data to a Parse database from a Google Apps Script function. I attempted to use the ParseDB library (https://script.google.com/macros/library/d/MxhsVzdWH6ZQMWWeAA9tObPxhMjh3Sh48/12), but I can't seem to get it working. It seems like I'm not accessing the ParseDBInstance correctly:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  // e.namedValues is an object containing question fields associated with lists of        responses
  var db = getMyDb('redacted',
                   'redacted',
                   'response');
  Logger.log(db);
  db.save({
   test: 'a_string'
  });
}
```

I can't find anything online indicating how I'm supposed to be doing this...and I feel like I'm just doing something dumb (pretty new to apps script/javascript in general/parse).

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: You may want to make sure you sanitise your code in future when posting here since you appear to have included your API keys in your code sample.  I have edited these out but they will still be visible to anyone who views the edit history of this question.  Therefore I would advise you to generate new API keys

Answer (score 0):

You need to click 'resources > libraries" then use the key "MxhsVzdWH6ZQMWWeAA9tObPxhMjh3Sh48"

You can then use the library by calling ParseDb.getMyDb(applicationId, restApiKey, class)

Comment: Looks good. Where did you find that key? Or did you make that library?

Comment: I didn't make it. The key makes part of the URL